# Sorting numbers using vector in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

Im trying to sort certain numbers from smallest to greatest using vector.When I try to run my code it only displays ----PRINT----- and ---END---
Im stuck. Im thinking if it has something to do with the fix function during the sorting process.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print(vector<int> vec)
 {
    cout<< "------PRINT---------"<< endl;
    for (vector<int>::const_iterator it=vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); ++it) 
    cout << *it << " ";

    cout << "------ END ------" << endl;
 }
  vector<int> fix(vector<string> numbers)
 {
           vector<int> result;  
           sort( result.begin(), result.end() );
           return result;
  }

 int main() 
{

vector<string> test;

test.push_back("5462");
test.push_back("5451");
test.push_back("7854");
test.push_back("221");


print(fix(test));

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `vector<int> result;` to `vector<int> result = numbers;`.

Replace all `vector<string>` to `vector<int>` and remove quote marks around numbers when you `push_back` them

Comment: It gives me error. 21:23: error: conversion from 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<int>' requested

Comment: It's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `fix` function, you are sorting `result` which is an empty vector.  This leads you to the other problem that you have a fundamental type mismatch requiring conversion.

If you want the result to be a `vector<int>`, you must to convert the strings to integers first.  Try this:

```
vector<int> fix( vector<string> numbers )
{
    vector<int> result;
    result.reserve( numbers.size() );
    std::transform( numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
        []( const string & s ) { return strtol( s.c_str(), NULL, 10 ); } );
    sort( result.begin(), result.end() );
    return result;
}
```

Read more here if you don't understand the above code:

- [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)
- [std::back_inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)
- [Lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)
- [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)

Note that this solution uses features added in C++11.

Answer (score -1):

Problems, problems everywhere

Problem 1.

```js
 vector<int> fix(vector<string> numbers)
 {
           vector<int> result;  <--- what is this?
           sort( result.begin(), result.end() );  <-- sort what? 
           return result;
  }
```

Problem 2.

```js
 vector<int> fix(vector<string> numbers)

 {
       // You wanna make vector<string> become vector<int> directly? nope
       // You have to convert yourself
       // or use something like result.push_back(atoi(numbers[i].c_str()))
           vector<int> result;  
           sort( result.begin(), result.end() );
           return result;
  }
```

Problem 3.

```js
void print(vector<int> vec)
 {
    cout<< "------PRINT---------"<< endl;
   // I seldom see people use iterator on vector<>... but it's ok
    for (vector<int>::const_iterator it=vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); ++it) 
    cout << *it << " ";
    
   // Missing cout << endl; alert
    cout << "------ END ------" << endl;
 }
```

To conclude, working version:

```js
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print(vector<int> vec)
 {
    cout<< "------PRINT---------"<< endl;
    for (vector<int>::const_iterator it=vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); ++it) 
    cout << *it << " ";
 
    cout << endl << "------ END ------" << endl;
 }
  vector<int> fix(vector<string> numbers)
 {
           vector<int> result; 
           for(int i=0, l =numbers.size(); i<l; i++) result.push_back(atoi(numbers[i].c_str()));
           sort( result.begin(), result.end() );
           return result;
  }

 int main() 
{

vector<string> test;

test.push_back("5462");
test.push_back("5451");
test.push_back("7854");
test.push_back("221");


print(fix(test));

return 0;
}
```